# Linux RStudio version seems to be looking for Windows plugins

Tags: r, rstudio

Out of the blue, apparently, RStudio has quit loading.  I uninstalled, reinstalled and from the terminal I got this message:

```
mike@mike-asrock:~$ rstudio
```

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
>   This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

My searching suggests that the references in the message above relate to  Windows.  This error persisted even after I reloaded Lubuntu (my preferred OS).  I simply can't figure out what RStudio is looking for.

Comment: The message above does not relate to Windows. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051790/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752917/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-on-archlinux-write-appimag etc.

Comment: Also, help us help you: We need more information. What OS are you on (e.g. Lubuntu 18.04)? What version of RStudio do you have? How did you install it?

Comment: I posted an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/675223/rstudio-does-not-launch-after-installation/1213490#1213490